# Bisecting passages of a perfect maze. Turning it into a unicursal maze

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, scaling, maze

## Question

I have a very simple maze (labyrinth) that I essentially want to double in size by bisecting the passage that runs through it. This is hard for me to explain in words so here's a diagram showing the original converted into the result I want:
[image]

## Problem

Naturally I have a 2D bool array that I have to double in size but I'm finding it really hard to even grasp how to do this scaling without breaking the unicursal rule of the maze?

> A unicursal maze is a maze without any junctions and choices. It is just one long passage which slows down the solver from reaching the end point.

## Attempt

My initial thinking was to find every neighbour of a passage node that is a wall and push them outwards by 2 tiles and then add a wall again where the neightbour used to be. This just resulted in this embarassing frankenstein:

[image]

## Research & Resources

- Another interesting visualization and explaining of the result I'm looking for was this:
  https://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=40832.msg1173956#msg1173956
- I have also acquired "Mazes for Progressmers by Jamis Buck" but sadly it didn't cover unicursal mazes.
- Jamis Buck actually seems to have a public repo for a unicursal maze generator written in Ruby. I find this language extremely difficult to parse though. Perhaps just some help explaining what is done will be enough to write my own in C#: https://github.com/jamis/theseus/blob/eff25e2d02da00bb9515690b83008ec05e852317/lib/theseus/orthogonal_maze.rb#L108

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1 is to triple the size of the passages in your maze without increase the  thickness of the walls.  That is easily accomplished by tripling every odd-numbered row (counting from 0), and then tripling every odd-numbered column.
2. Then, fill every cell that has no filled neighbors in this doubled maze.  That will get you a maze with one big loop.
3. Then, fill any empty cell to break the loop. Put the start and end on either side of this cell.

Passages tripled:

```
#########
#       #
#       #
#       #
#####   #
#       #
#       #
#       #
#########
```

Fill cells with no filled neighbor:

```
#########
#       #
# ##### #
#     # #
##### # #
#     # #
# ##### #
#       #
#########
```

Break the loop:

```
#########
#s#e    #
# ##### #
#     # #
##### # #
#     # #
# ##### #
#       #
#########
```

Note that to get pleasing results, you should *not* start with a unicursal maze.  As long as the starting maze is a tree, which is what you get from the popular algorithms, the result will be unicursal.

Unfortunately, this algorithm only produces mazes with the exit one space away from the entrance.  It's good that this seems to be what you want, because getting them on opposite sides of the maze is tricky.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. There just one part thats confusing me and I'm not sure how to implmenent on the 2D array. It is this: `That is easily accomplished by tripling every odd-numbered row (counting from 0), and then tripling every odd-numbered column.` Why every odd?

Comment: The even-numbered columns contain the vertical walls, and the even-numbered rows contain the horizontal walls.  You don't want to multiply those, because you don't want to make the walls thicker.

Comment: Wouldn't that just apply to the current maze? If a maze of a different configuration was generated it wouldn't work right? e.g. some odd rows have walls, some don't.

Comment: Odd rows only have vertical walls in them.  When you triple the odd rows, the vertical walls get longer, not thicker.